# Python compare two lists and adding value to a third list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a function that takes in two lists that can only contain 3 elements, compares each element, and adds 1 to a third list. Example:

```
in :a = [1,2,3]
    b = [3,2,1]
out: result = [1,1]
```

so here the result is `[1,1]` because `b[0]>a[0], b[1] = a[1]`, and b`[2]<a[2]`.

I have the following code:

```
def compareTriplets(a, b):
    a = a[:3]
    b = b[:3]
    result = [0,0]
    for i,j in  list(zip(a,b)):
        if a[i] > b[j]:
            result[0] += 1
        elif a[i] < b[j]:
            result[1] += 1
    return result
```

but this gives me the error "index out of range." what am i doing wrong here? am i at least on the right track? I can do this easily by changing the inputs to 6 numbers, but having lists as inputs is throwing me off.

Comment: so 1 if `b[i]>=a[i]`?

Comment: `i` and `j` reference the values within the list, not some counter. `3` is in both lists and is an invalid index for lists of that size.

Comment: No, it has to be strictly greater than. if b[i] = a[i] then nothing happens

Comment: Under the assumption that `a` is a 3-elemement list, the line `a = a[:3]` is pointless. If you want your function to be defined for lists with more than 3 elements, the name of the function wouldn't quite make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looping through the values of the lists `a` and `b` and then trying to index the list with the values. You need to remove the `a[i]` and `j[i]` in your function and use `i` and `j` instead:

```
def compareTriplets(a, b):
    a = a[:3]
    b = b[:3]
    result = [0,0]
    for i,j in  list(zip(a,b)):
        if i > j:
            result[0] += 1
        elif i < j:
            result[1] += 1
    return result

a = [1,2,3]
b = [3,2,1]

print (compareTriplets(a, b))
# [1, 1]
```

Comment: This is just what i was looking for, I figured it was something minor. Thanks!

Comment: @DBA108642 you could also use `reduce` for this (albeit it harder to grok what you're doing), eg: `functools.reduce(lambda x, y: (x[0] + (y[0] > y[1]), x[1] + (y[0] < y[1])), zip(a[:3], b[:3]), (0, 0))`...

Comment: @JonClements my eyes!

Answer (score 2):

You are using `a[i]` instead of `i` (and same for `b[j]`). Here is the fixed code:

```
def compareTriplets(a, b):
    a = a[:3]
    b = b[:3]
    result = [0,0]
    for i,j in  list(zip(a,b)):
        if i > j:
            result[0] += 1
        elif i < j:
            result[1] += 1
    return result


a = [1,2,3]
b = [3,2,1]

print(compareTriplets(a,b))  # [1, 1]
```

And here is a one-line style solution, which is very short:

```
def compareTriplets(a, b):
    return [sum(r) for r in zip(*((i>j, i<j) for i,j in zip(a,b)))]

a = [1,2,3]
b = [3,2,1]

print(compareTriplets(a,b))  # [1, 1]
```

Note that it works also for lists with more than 3 elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` to iterate elements for `a` and `b` in pairs, create a 2 element list based on whether a's element or b's element is greater and then `sum` the result

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [3,2,1]
>>> list(map(sum, (zip(*((x>y, y>x) for x,y in zip(a,b))))))
[1, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can convert your original list to numpy, then this is the best method.

```
a = np.array([3,2,1])
b = np.array([1,2,3])

c = np.ones(np.not_equal(a, b).sum(), dtype=int)
```

**Outputs**

```
c = array([ 1, 1])
```